# Using Checkbox to Toggle Image Size Between Its Resized Size & Original Size with Scrollbars

Tags: html, css, image, toggle

I have an application that uses a master html template to construct html pages for different products. Each product has a number of photos assigned to it within the app. The app automatically inserts a img tag for each photo into a copy of the master template using a internal loop and generates a web page for that product.

When each image first appears it should be resized to fit its parent container division. When the user clicks the image the first time I want the image to be shown at its original size with vertical and horizontal scrollbars inside its parent container. If the user clicks the image a second time it returns to its restrained size. I don't want the parent container to change in size when the user clicks the image.

I am attempting to use a input checkbox to do this, but cannot seem to get the code right to toggle back and forth.

What I attempting to do is allow the user to do is to initially see a series of vertically stacked thumbnail images which are automatically displayed at 90% of their screen width. If they want to see more detail I want them to click a image and scroll over the full size image within its parent division.

In the past I've used a simple "" target link to allow them to see the full size images but this will not be permitted in the near future (i.e., no off site links allowed). I also cannot use any scripts, iframes, or any other techniques that would be flagged as "active content".

I am using the following css and html. I've used each image's index within the program (0, 1, 2, etc.) to provide a unique input id and label for attribute for each image. The first image would thus have 0 assigned to each of these attributes, while the second image would have 1.

```
.imgholder .checkimg{
    display:none;
}

.imgholder{
    position:relative;
    width:90vw;
    overflow:auto;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    clear: both;
}

img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}

.checkimg:checked ~ label img{

}


<!--Begin Program Loop-->

<div class="imgholder">
<input class="checkimg" type="checkbox" id="[[image.index]]"><label for="[[image.index]]"><img src="[[image.imageURL]]"></label>
</div>

<!--End Program Loop-->
```

Comment: Could you put this in a Codepen or JSFiddle, please?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example. This only shows how to achieve the main functionality. You will probably have to play with the sizing of the images, as they can be distorted due to weird aspect ratios.

```css
.imgholder {
  position: relative;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  clear: both;
}

.imgholder .checkimg{
  display: none;
}


img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.checkimg:checked + img {
  width: auto;
  max-height: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgholder">
  <label for="i1">
    <input class="checkimg" type="checkbox" id="i1">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/1000/500"/>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="imgholder">
  <label for="i2">
    <input class="checkimg" type="checkbox" id="i2">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/1000/500"/>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="imgholder">
  <label for="i3">
    <input class="checkimg" type="checkbox" id="i3">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/1000/500"/>
  </label>
</div>
```